# How can I get "Event Name & Method Name" via Polygonscan API?

Tags: ethereum, erc20

Currently, the company which I am working in, they want to make a statistics system for P2E games which have (or will have) ERC-20 tokens based on Polygon.

I have to accumulate the logs came from blockchain networks and game servers to know how much tokens players earn/spend, and the productivity of each contents/activities.

So, I need to get "The event name & method name" from polygonscan API. unfortunately, Polygonscan API just offer "Transfer Logs" only instead of offering all of logs.

https://docs.polygonscan.com/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-erc-20-token-transfer-events-by-address

I found this api will return results with "Input" column. but it has just "deprecated" as value. is there any way to get what I want?

- I choose "ethereum" as tags instead of "polygon" if I disturb you, I apologize this. I think ethereum has similar system with polygon because Polygon is based on Ethereum. and, the "Polygon" tags, as you know, it is for "3D rendering" not for crypto coins.

Comment: Ever find a way to get the method name?

Comment: I am running into this same issue and would also love help